# Resolving ip public address to 127.0.0.1

Tags: ip, local, public

Good day all,

I'm in the process of locally testing a website and I need to replicate the production environment. This website is available on a public ip address (no domain for it yet), and I need to 'override' the public ip address with a local ip address for which I've setup a virtual host locally.

Point is, I can't 'override' the public access. I'm using windows, and I've tried using the hosts file, the 'route' and 'arp' commands, but I don't think these are the correct tools. Hosts file only accepts domains, and I might not be skilled enough to issue the proper route or arp commands.

Example:
ping 85.85.82.83 <= NOT A DOMAIN NAME
reply 127.0.0.1

So please help me redirect a public ip address to a local ip address, so that a simple 'ping' of the originally public ip address points instead to the local ip address assigned.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to assign multiple IP addresses to your local network card. One would of your local LAN and the other IP address will be of your production server. Steps are given on [Creating an alias IP address (Microsoft Windows)](http://www.ssh.com/manuals/guardian-admin/31/proc-alias-windows.html) website.

Comment: thanks, but this falls short, since my test system is connected to the internet, and actually 'creates an ip address collision' this way. besides, this would actually make my test system reply to the public ip address, which is different from overriding the public ip address.

Answer (score 3):

If I catch you correctly you Are looking for a to resolve an ip Adress to local Adress. Not a domain. In windows this can be done by **setting up an ip security rule**. See [this scribd tutorial](http://www.scribd.com/doc/39894749/Block-specific-IP-address-in-windows-using-IP-Security) I made long ago. It's for blocking an ip Address by redirecting it to localhost. So things will be same for you.

If you want to automate it you can use [netsh](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725926%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) or [ipseccmd](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ipsecmd.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Awesome! Just 45 simple steps ;p

Comment: There must be command line equivalent.but I don't know this. Besides I tried to make this more verbose for non technical user. I think it'll be easy for you.

Comment: It is probably accessible via `netsh`.

Comment: Looks exactly what I need. Let me check it out.

Comment: @leppie you are right. I just googled and found ipseccmd is another tool for this.

Comment: Sadly the policy doesn't allow to 'change' the source IP. I can just allow or deny the traffic, but it doesn't change source or destination. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Host file does work in Windows. Use it every day. You have to use the correct one though.
On my PC (64-bits Windows), it's in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. (no extension, don't use the hosts.sam for example, if you have one).

Format is rather straigthforward: on each line, you start with the IP address, then a list of hosts resolving to this IP address (separate each with space character).

If the site you want to test is www.my.site.com, and your local IP is 192.168.0.1, just insert:

```
192.168.0.1 www.my.site.com
```

But beware, if you've already been to the real www.my.site.com, Windows keeps the resolved IP in cache. So you have to flush the cache, so your resolver forgets the previous IP. To do this, call from a Windows prompt:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

route and arp won't help you in your problem, since it's the hostname resolution you want to solve.
Once you've done your modification, you can test, always from the command prompt, with a simple ping command:

```
ping www.my.site.com
```

It will give you the IP of the host it's trying to ping.

Comment: I made it clearer now in the original question. The problem is with an IP ADDRESS. I too use the hosts file everyday, but it only manages domain names, and not public ip addresses like http://85.85.82.83 (or at least not to my knowledge)

Comment: OP wants to map IP, not a hostname.

Comment: OK, you're right it's much clearer now, sorry for the misunderstanding. Well, what you need is Network Address Translation (NAT) (even though it would be easier, I think, to translate 85.85.82.83 to your NIC IP instead of localhost). Not an easy thing on Windows, unless you have Windows Server edition (2008 I think). One very twisted way could be to install a linux virtual machine on your pc, with the target IP you need, and then have it NAT back to your pc. Could take long. But still, you would have to "borrow" the IP address.